# Градиент для текста на чем угодно (css или javascript )

Tags: градиент, javascript, html, css

Добрый вечер. Нужно сделать градиент для текста (вертикальный) без картинок, желательно на js, пытался найти плагин, нашел

https://github.com/Kapinko/CJAF/blob/5efddc1bf65a40ae428d469e626b911698ff27d1/lib/jquery/jquery.fonteffect.js

но, оф сайт не работает, без примера не разобрался, поможет кто разобраться с этим? или может знаете еще какие способы? спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать див с градиентом и сверху второй див с прозрачным текстом.

```
color: transparent
```

Градиенты можно генерировать [здесь](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). Только нужно не забыть назначить background верхнему диву и спозиционировать его правильно.

Comment: будет время попробую, спасибо!